# Taylor expansion of a multi-variables composite function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I have a general function, **U**, which has the following form,
$$
U(r-r^{'})
$$
where **r** and **r'** are defined as,
$$
r = R + u(R) 
\\
r^{'} = R^{'} + u(R^{'})
$$
For every **R** and **R'**, **u** is just small variations around them and it is a function of 3 coordinate variables, **x**, **y**, and **z**.

What is the Taylor expansion of **U**? Also, I need it as a compact summation expression.

Comment: Is your function $\mathbf{U}$ also a vector function? The notation $U(r-r')$ suggests it's a scalar function. Can you clarify? I'm suspecting this is a question on crystals and $U$ is the potential energy, which is a scalar.

Comment: Yes, it is the potential energy of crystals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you have a function $f: \mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$ (which is how the potential energy works, from a vector to a scalar), then
$$
f(\vec{x}+\vec{h})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(\vec{h}\cdot \vec{\nabla})^nf(\vec{x})
$$
In your problem, $d=3$ i.e. 3D space, $f=U$ potential energy, $\vec{x}=\vec{R}-\vec{R}'$ and $\vec{h}=\vec{u}(\vec{R})-\vec{u}(\vec{R}')$.